# Point domain to github pages

Tags: redirect, github, dns, subdomain, hosting

So I have a domain registered with 1&1 and I recently decided to create my website using github pages. I added as github told me to, but how can I make my domain point to my github page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue? How? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read following article on github.

https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/

There is a lot of help on github and google around this issue.

Comment: The issue I have now is that the two domains keep redirecting towards each other and they both have no content now. You will simply receive an empty webpage

Comment: remove redirects you have and follow the guide

Comment: The guide is what led me to my problem. Is there anyway I can simply start over?

Comment: Remove CNAME and A records and save it then start again after checking that these records have propagated properly. it might take 2 to 24 hours to show your changes.